# Charmed K8s - Volume not created by Ceph storage class

Tags: juju, kubernetes, ceph

I've deployed an on premise baremetal K8s Cloud with charmed Kubernetes. And I use Ceph for the storage.

The deployment of the cluster went well but when I want to create a Volume (via a PVC) the volume stays in the `Pending` state. In the logs there is an error specifying that there is already an operation on this volume ID and then a timeout is exceeded.

I followed more or less the tutorial from Canonical (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-ceph-backed-kubernetes-cluster#1-overview) without success.

Here or some more info :

The ceph pools :

```
root@infra01:~/k8s-test# juju run-action --wait ceph-mon/leader list-pools
unit-ceph-mon-0:
  UnitId: ceph-mon/0
  id: "28"
  results:
    message: |
      1 device_health_metrics
      2 xfs-pool
      3 ext4-pool
  status: completed
  timing:
    completed: 2021-04-27 14:34:02 +0000 UTC
    enqueued: 2021-04-27 14:34:01 +0000 UTC
    started: 2021-04-27 14:34:01 +0000 UTC
```

The storage class :

```
root@infra01:~# kubectl describe sc
Name:            ceph-ext4
IsDefaultClass:  No
Annotations:     kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"allowVolumeExpansion":true,"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"cdk-addons":"true"},"name":"ceph-ext4"},"mountOptions":["discard"],"parameters":{"clusterID":"4898f638-a1a7-11eb-a288-5bcd87ddd233","csi.storage.k8s.io/controller-expand-secret-name":"csi-rbd-secret","csi.storage.k8s.io/controller-expand-secret-namespace":"default","csi.storage.k8s.io/fstype":"ext4","csi.storage.k8s.io/node-stage-secret-name":"csi-rbd-secret","csi.storage.k8s.io/node-stage-secret-namespace":"default","csi.storage.k8s.io/provisioner-secret-name":"csi-rbd-secret","csi.storage.k8s.io/provisioner-secret-namespace":"default","imageFeatures":"layering","pool":"ext4-pool"},"provisioner":"rbd.csi.ceph.com","reclaimPolicy":"Delete"}

Provisioner:           rbd.csi.ceph.com
Parameters:            clusterID=4898f638-a1a7-11eb-a288-5bcd87ddd233,csi.storage.k8s.io/controller-expand-secret-name=csi-rbd-secret,csi.storage.k8s.io/controller-expand-secret-namespace=default,csi.storage.k8s.io/fstype=ext4,csi.storage.k8s.io/node-stage-secret-name=csi-rbd-secret,csi.storage.k8s.io/node-stage-secret-namespace=default,csi.storage.k8s.io/provisioner-secret-name=csi-rbd-secret,csi.storage.k8s.io/provisioner-secret-namespace=default,imageFeatures=layering,pool=ext4-pool
AllowVolumeExpansion:  True
MountOptions:
  discard
ReclaimPolicy:      Delete
VolumeBindingMode:  Immediate
Events:             <none>


Name:            ceph-xfs
IsDefaultClass:  Yes
Annotations:     kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"allowVolumeExpansion":true,"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"},"labels":{"cdk-addons":"true"},"name":"ceph-xfs"},"mountOptions":["discard"],"parameters":{"clusterID":"4898f638-a1a7-11eb-a288-5bcd87ddd233","csi.storage.k8s.io/controller-expand-secret-name":"csi-rbd-secret","csi.storage.k8s.io/controller-expand-secret-namespace":"default","csi.storage.k8s.io/fstype":"xfs","csi.storage.k8s.io/node-stage-secret-name":"csi-rbd-secret","csi.storage.k8s.io/node-stage-secret-namespace":"default","csi.storage.k8s.io/provisioner-secret-name":"csi-rbd-secret","csi.storage.k8s.io/provisioner-secret-namespace":"default","imageFeatures":"layering","pool":"xfs-pool"},"provisioner":"rbd.csi.ceph.com","reclaimPolicy":"Delete"}
,storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class=true
Provisioner:           rbd.csi.ceph.com
Parameters:            clusterID=4898f638-a1a7-11eb-a288-5bcd87ddd233,csi.storage.k8s.io/controller-expand-secret-name=csi-rbd-secret,csi.storage.k8s.io/controller-expand-secret-namespace=default,csi.storage.k8s.io/fstype=xfs,csi.storage.k8s.io/node-stage-secret-name=csi-rbd-secret,csi.storage.k8s.io/node-stage-secret-namespace=default,csi.storage.k8s.io/provisioner-secret-name=csi-rbd-secret,csi.storage.k8s.io/provisioner-secret-namespace=default,imageFeatures=layering,pool=xfs-pool
AllowVolumeExpansion:  True
MountOptions:
  discard
ReclaimPolicy:      Delete
VolumeBindingMode:  Immediate
Events:             <none>
```

And the persistant volume claim :

```
root@infra01:~/k8s-test# kubectl describe pvc myvol
Name:          myvol
Namespace:     pa-cnfdevops-paccard
StorageClass:  ceph-xfs
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: rbd.csi.ceph.com
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age                    From                                                                                              Message
  ----     ------                ----                   ----                                                                                              -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed    34m                    rbd.csi.ceph.com_csi-rbdplugin-provisioner-549c6b54c6-5ddcl_a95b48b7-31eb-4cc5-bcbe-2715dbd43451  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "ceph-xfs": rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
  Normal   Provisioning          32m (x9 over 37m)      rbd.csi.ceph.com_csi-rbdplugin-provisioner-549c6b54c6-5ddcl_a95b48b7-31eb-4cc5-bcbe-2715dbd43451  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "pa-cnfdevops-paccard/myvol"
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed    32m (x8 over 34m)      rbd.csi.ceph.com_csi-rbdplugin-provisioner-549c6b54c6-5ddcl_a95b48b7-31eb-4cc5-bcbe-2715dbd43451  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "ceph-xfs": rpc error: code = Aborted desc = an operation with the given Volume ID pvc-0414bcd6-38ff-4523-b2bd-93e3ef58eea5 already exists
  Normal   ExternalProvisioning  31m (x26 over 36m)     persistentvolume-controller                                                                       waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "rbd.csi.ceph.com" or manually created by system administrator
  Normal   ExternalProvisioning  28m (x5 over 29m)      persistentvolume-controller                                                                       waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "rbd.csi.ceph.com" or manually created by system administrator
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed    27m                    rbd.csi.ceph.com_csi-rbdplugin-provisioner-549c6b54c6-9r2nh_11ff8e47-a296-401e-8f08-799f22fd5a02  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "ceph-xfs": rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
  Normal   Provisioning          4m4s (x14 over 30m)    rbd.csi.ceph.com_csi-rbdplugin-provisioner-549c6b54c6-9r2nh_11ff8e47-a296-401e-8f08-799f22fd5a02  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "pa-cnfdevops-paccard/myvol"
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed    4m4s (x12 over 27m)    rbd.csi.ceph.com_csi-rbdplugin-provisioner-549c6b54c6-9r2nh_11ff8e47-a296-401e-8f08-799f22fd5a02  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "ceph-xfs": rpc error: code = Aborted desc = an operation with the given Volume ID pvc-0414bcd6-38ff-4523-b2bd-93e3ef58eea5 already exists
  Normal   ExternalProvisioning  2m53s (x105 over 27m)  persistentvolume-controller                                                                       waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "rbd.csi.ceph.com" or manually created by system administrator
```

Does any of you guys know what can cause that and how to fix it ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and in my case the problem was I didn't have connectivity from the pods towards the ceph cluster.
I was using Calico CNI and due to this issue [LP#1895547](https://bugs.launchpad.net/charm-calico/+bug/1895547) external traffic from the k8s cluster was not being NAT. Thus return traffic from the ceph cluster was going nowhere.

My solution was to set `net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter: 1` on all worker nodes. I used the sysconfig charm to do this.

Hope this helps!